# AngularJS Timer Alarm Clock

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I understand how to display the system time/date. I also have textboxes where user input the time that they want to input. I'll call it 1st alarm.

What I want to do is check if once the system time reaches the 1st alarm, it'll do something. I currently have a text label but that's not the important part.

In the html part i have here

```
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter Time Start Here" ng-model="firstAlert"/>{{firstAlert}}
        <button type="button" ng-click="Check()">Submit</button>
```

In the JS part

```
$scope.Check=function(){
    if(Date.now() == $scope.firstAlert)
    {
        $scope.info = "They're the same!";
    }
}
```

What I would like to know is what would be the best approach in doing this. Obviously my first though is not the correct one. I've search for some examples but I mainly came across on how to do a timer and that's not what I'm focused on. I simply would like to have the user type in the date and time (mm/dd/yy hh:mm PM or AM). Or rather in the "short" date format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use angular's [$interval](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval) or [$timeout](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout)

Your logic in `Check` will probably have to be more granular, but this roughly what you'd want if you wanted to check every 1s:

```
$interval($scope.Check, 1000);
```

Comment: I've looked here, https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date, for understanding of dates and I would like it for the user to put the format like 1/1/2014 10:30AM. I understand that the date format converts it to something readable, otherwise it's in a huge list of numbers, UTC format? I think i'm converting 'short' format to some really long list of number?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming $scope.fisrtAlert is in the correct format, you might want to do this.

```
var timer = $interval(function(){
   if($scope.firstAlert && Date.now()==$scope.firstAlert){
      $scope.info = "Ring Ring";
   }
}, 1000);

$scope.stopTimer = function(){
  $interval.cancel(timer);
}
```